# Conditional selection of RowNum in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, rownum

I have written a query which returns me following data.

```
ID  EmpFirstName    EmpLastName RowNum
1     X                  Y        1
2     A                  B        1
3     A                  B        2
```

Now I want all records where `RowNum` is >1. For example, in this case I need 2 and 3 record in output.

If I put condition `RowNum >1` then I will get only third record but I want 2 as well.

Comment: If the second record has `RowNum` = `1`, then why would you want that in your result set?  This sounds contradictory to me.

Comment: Actually @TimBiegeleisen If set has any duplicate records then I need full record information. There are many fields in original dataset and obviously duplicate will be deleted but to make decision both records need in output. If I select `RowNum = 2` then decision cannot be taken whether to delete 2nd record or 1st record.

Comment: I see the duplicate first and second row, but their `RowNum` value is still less than 1.  Why include them?

Comment: what query you try ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - First and Second row are different (based on EMP Name).. second and third are same.. RowNum is defining which are duplicate.. I have placed partition which is resulting correct value..

Comment: @ChanomFirst For the result set I want.. I couldn't write anything yet.. any help?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your query is this:

```
select ID, EmpFirstName, EmpLastName,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpFirstName, EmpLastName ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum
FROM aTable
```

This is a classic query used to filter out any duplicate values.

In order effectively select all the records with the duplicate values I can suggest using the COUNT() window function:

```
;with a as (
    select ID, EmpFirstName, EmpLastName,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpFirstName, EmpLastName ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpFirstName, EmpLastName) AS cnt
    FROM aTable
)
SELECT * FROM a where cnt > 1
ORDER BY EmpFirstName, EmpLastName
```

To test it use this query:

```
drop table #tmp
CREATE table #tmp (ID int , EmpFirstName varchar(10) ,   EmpLastName varchar(10))
go
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES 
    (1,'X','Y' )
    ,(2,'A','B')
    ,(3,'A','B')
    ,(4,'A','C')
    ,(5,'B','C')
    ,(6,'B','C')


;with a as (
    select ID, EmpFirstName, EmpLastName,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpFirstName, EmpLastName ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum,
    COUNT(id) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpFirstName, EmpLastName) AS cnt
    FROM #tmp
)
SELECT * FROM a where cnt > 1
ORDER BY EmpFirstName, EmpLastName
```

Result:

```
ID          EmpFirstName EmpLastName RowNum               cnt
----------- ------------ ----------- -------------------- -----------
2           A            B           1                    2
3           A            B           2                    2
5           B            C           1                    2
6           B            C           2                    2
```

Comment: I liked the logic `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpFirstName, EmpLastName) AS cnt` but it didn't work.. It is counting over EmpFirstName irrespective of lastname :(

Comment: works for me: `drop table #tmp
CREATE table #tmp (ID int , EmpFirstName varchar(10) ,   EmpLastName varchar(10))
go
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES 
    (1,'X','Y' )
    ,(2,'A','B')
    ,(3,'A','B')
    ,(4,'A','C')
    ,(5,'B','C')
    ,(6,'B','C')


;with a as (
    select ID, EmpFirstName, EmpLastName,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpFirstName, EmpLastName ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpFirstName, EmpLastName) AS cnt
    FROM #tmp
)
SELECT * FROM a where cnt > 1`

Comment: ok, I think I figured why it seems to you that it is counting by EmpFirstName, it is because your result set is unsorted. Add `ORDER BY EmpFirstName, EmpLastName` to the end of the query and you will get the correct result

Answer (score 0):

I make sample data and use this query

```
CREATE table #tmp (ID int , EmpFirstName varchar(10) ,   EmpLastName varchar(10) ,RowNum int)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES 
    (1,'X','Y',1)
    ,(2,'A','B',1)
    ,(3,'A','B',2)

SELECT ID,EmpFirstName,EmpLastName,RowNum
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS [NEWrownum]
    FROM #tmp
) q
WHERE q.NEWrownum > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
DECLARE @Result TABLE (ID INT, EmpFirstName VARCHAR(10), EmpLastName VARCHAR(10), RowNum INT)

INSERT INTO @Result
VALUES
     (1, 'X', 'Y', 1)
    ,(2, 'A', 'B', 1)
    ,(3, 'A', 'B', 2)

SELECT r1.*
FROM @Result r1
INNER JOIN (SELECT *        -- get duplicate records
            FROM @Result
            WHERE RowNum = 2                
            ) as r2 ON r1.EmpFirstName = r2.EmpFirstName
                    AND r1.EmpLastName = r2.EmpLastName
```